# custom authentication with devise for an API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, api, authentication, devise

so i have a little tricky combination here

```
Company has many Users
User belongs to Company
```

The User is managed for authentication with devise

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :company

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
```

You can login as a User and create Objects that all belong to the Company of that, not to the user, for example: `Text`. (`company.texts`)

now i created a simple API using the `acts_as_api` gem.
for this i simply have to modify my text-controller, f.e. the show action.

```
class TextsController < ApplicationController

  load_and_authorize_resource

  def show
    #@text = Text.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json { render_for_api :texts_all, :json => @text }
    end
```

this works quite fine on the website.
the problem is the API. i don't want to authenticate when accessing the api via the user model. the company does have a attribute called `:hash`which i want to use for Auth in the API.

i don't have any idea how to achieve this using devise (or any other method).
so by default devise wants a user to be logged in because of `load_and_authorize_resource` in my controller which is fine for the html response but not for the json response.

any ideas?

thanks for reading this. please leave a comment if something is unclear!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use Token Authenticatable and send the token with each request on your API.

[Here is a tutorial for it.](http://zyphdesignco.com/blog/simple-auth-token-example-with-devise)

Comment: i also saw this, but the token is from the company which is not a devise model.

Comment: the link is dead

Answer (score 0):

Conditionally apply auth filters based on accepted format headers:

```
# override in controllers related ot API
def authenticate_user!
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { super } # just like before
    format.json { enforce_api_auth }
  end
end
```

Now API calls enforce their own auth.