# Devise JWT "You need to sign in or sign up before continuing"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, jwt

you're my last chance
I try to move from `devise_token_auth` to `devise-jwt`
When I try to sign_in a user, devise respond with : "You need to sign in or sign up before continuing."
Config :

- devise 4.7.1
- devise_jwt 0.8
- rails 6.0
- ruby 2.7.1

There is my code :

```
module Api
  module V2
    module Devise
      class SessionsController < ::Devise::SessionsController
        skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token
        include ::Api::V2::Concerns::Response

        respond_to :json

        private

        def respond_with(resource, _opts = {})
          render_json ::V2::UserSerializer.new(resource)
        end

        def respond_to_on_destroy
          head :ok
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

part of routes.rb :

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  scope '(:locale)', locale: /#{I18n.available_locales.join('|')}/, defaults: { format: 'json' } do
    namespace :api do
      namespace :v2 do
        devise_for :users, path: 'auth',
                           skip: %i[passwords], controllers: {
                             registrations: 'api/v2/devise/registrations',
                             sessions: 'api/v2/devise/sessions'
                           }
        resources :destinations, only: :index
        resources :photos, only: :index

        scope :user do
          resources :client_contracts, only: :index, module: :user
          resources :contracts_houses, only: :index, module: :user
          resource :owner_certificate, only: :show, module: :user
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

(I have devise also working with admin_users (not jwt) and I have disabled routes of devise_token_auth for api_v1_user : )

```
        mount_devise_token_auth_for 'User', at: 'auth',
                                            skip: %i[confirmations passwords registrations sessions
                                                     token_validations]
```

Devise initializer :

```
  config.skip_session_storage = %i[http_auth]
  config.navigational_formats = ['*/*', :html, :pdf]
  config.jwt do |jwt|
    jwt.secret = ENV['DEVISE_JWT_SECRET_KEY']
    jwt.expiration_time = 1.day.to_i
  end
```

User model :

```
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable,
         :jwt_authenticatable, jwt_revocation_strategy: JWTDenylist

  self.skip_session_storage = %i[http_auth params_auth]
```

I tried to register a new user and it works but with cookies (devise return cookies), not JWT in header...

Devise conf :

```
> Devise::JWT.config
=> #<Dry::Configurable::Config values={:secret=>"secret", :expiration_time=>86400, :dispatch_requests=>[["POST", /^\/(:locale)\/api\/v2\/auth\/sign_in$/], ["POST", /^\/(\/:locale)\/api\/v1\/auth\/sign_in$/], ["POST", /^\/(\/:locale)\/api\/v1\/auth$/], ["POST", /^\/(\/:locale)\/api\/v2\/auth\/sign_in$/], ["POST", /^\/(\/:locale)\/api\/v2\/auth$/]], :revocation_requests=>[], :aud_header=>"JWT_AUD", :request_formats=>{}}>


> Warden::JWTAuth.config
=> #<Dry::Configurable::Config values={:secret=>"secret", :algorithm=>"HS256", :expiration_time=>86400, :aud_header=>"JWT_AUD", :mappings=>{:api_v1_user=>User (call 'User.connection' to establish a connection), :api_v2_user=>User (call 'User.connection' to establish a connection)}, :dispatch_requests=>[["POST", /^\/(:locale)\/api\/v2\/auth\/sign_in$/], ["POST", /^\/(\/:locale)\/api\/v1\/auth\/sign_in$/], ["POST", /^\/(\/:locale)\/api\/v1\/auth$/], ["POST", /^\/(\/:locale)\/api\/v2\/auth\/sign_in$/], ["POST", /^\/(\/:locale)\/api\/v2\/auth$/]], :revocation_requests=>[["DELETE", /^\/(\/:locale)\/api\/v1\/auth\/sign_out$/], ["DELETE", /^\/(\/:locale)\/api\/v2\/auth\/sign_out$/]], :revocation_strategies=>{:api_v1_user=>JWTDenylist (call 'JWTDenylist.connection' to establish a connection), :api_v2_user=>JWTDenylist (call 'JWTDenylist.connection' to establish a connection)}}>


> Devise.mappings
=> {:admin_admin_user=>#<Devise::Mapping:0x0000555fd7602188 @scoped_path="admin/admin_users", @singular=:admin_admin_user, @class_name="AdminUser", @klass=#<Devise::Getter:0x0000555fd7601ad0 @name="AdminUser">, @path="admin_users", @path_prefix="(/:locale)/admin", @sign_out_via=:delete, @format=nil, @router_name=nil, @failure_app=Devise::FailureApp, @controllers={:registrations=>"admin/devise/registrations", :sessions=>"admin/devise/sessions", :passwords=>"admin/devise/passwords"}, @path_names={:registration=>"", :new=>"new", :edit=>"edit", :sign_in=>"sign_in", :sign_out=>"sign_out", :password=>"password"}, @modules=[:database_authenticatable, :recoverable], @routes=[:session, :password], @used_routes=[:session, :password], @used_helpers=[:session, :password]>, :api_v1_user=>#<Devise::Mapping:0x0000555fd6e718d8 @scoped_path="api_v1/users", @singular=:api_v1_user, @class_name="User", @klass=#<Devise::Getter:0x0000555fd6e71720 @name="User">, @path="auth", @path_prefix="(/:locale)/api/v1", @sign_out_via=:delete, @format=nil, @router_name=nil, @failure_app=Devise::FailureApp, @controllers={:unlocks=>"devise_token_auth/unlocks"}, @path_names={:registration=>"", :new=>"new", :edit=>"edit"}, @modules=[:database_authenticatable, :rememberable, :recoverable, :registerable, :validatable, :jwt_authenticatable], @routes=[:session, :password, :registration], @used_routes=[], @used_helpers=[:session, :password, :registration]>, :api_v2_user=>#<Devise::Mapping:0x0000555fd60297f8 @scoped_path="api_v2/users", @singular=:api_v2_user, @class_name="User", @klass=#<Devise::Getter:0x0000555fd60292d0 @name="User">, @path="auth", @path_prefix="(/:locale)/api/v2", @sign_out_via=:delete, @format=nil, @router_name=nil, @failure_app=Devise::FailureApp, @controllers={:registrations=>"api/v2/devise/registrations", :sessions=>"api/v2/devise/sessions"}, @path_names={:registration=>"", :new=>"new", :edit=>"edit", :sign_in=>"sign_in", :sign_out=>"sign_out", :sign_up=>"sign_up", :cancel=>"cancel"}, @modules=[:database_authenticatable, :rememberable, :recoverable, :registerable, :validatable, :jwt_authenticatable], @routes=[:session, :password, :registration], @used_routes=[:session, :registration], @used_helpers=[:session, :password, :registration]>}
```

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue, but then I realized that by doing `devise_for` inside namespace, Devise Controller assigns `resource_name` to `api/v1/user` (or something like that).

Can you try to move `devise_for` outside of all `namespace` blocks and change its path to `path: 'api/v2/auth'`?

i think this should help! Let me know it it did, please

Comment: absolute winner! I had been fighting with this for a day, thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

I'm too late but hope it will help somehow someone. I too faced similar issue. The solution provided by @Dmitry works nicely.

Though say if you still want to have the routes wrapped inside `namespace`, below is the alternative:

```ruby
namespace :api do
  namespace :v1 do
    devise_for :users, defaults: { format: :json }, singular: :user, controllers: {
      confirmations: "api/v1/users/confirmations",
      omniauth_callbacks: "api/v1/users/omniauth_callbacks",
      passwords: "api/v1/users/passwords",
      registrations: "api/v1/users/registrations",
      sessions: "api/v1/users/sessions",
      unlocks: "api/v1/users/unlocks",
    }
  end
end
```

Notice the `singular` option passed to `devise_for`. This will create the `resource_name` as `user` instead of `api_v1_user`. Also it will create proper helper for user, e.g. `current_user` or `authenticate_user!`. So a standard code for user will be maintained and you don't need to change when api version changes.